# WP 301 redirect does not work

Tags: redirect

Usually on my WP sites when I change the URL, WP automatically creates a 301 redirect.

Lets say I have this URL:

```
www.site.com/ugly-long-url
```

If I change it to

```
www.site.com/nice-url
```

Then when I visit the old URL (ugly-long-url) it automatically 301 redirects to the nice-url.
However I bought a website recently and whenever I change the URL, the old url gives me a 404 error.

It only works if I add the link manually to the htaccess file.

How can I get the automatic 301 redirection of WP back?

Comment: Without seeing code it's impossible to say.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.